# pagination on multiple tables on same page AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dirpagination

Hi I am facing issue while integrating dir-pagination on multiple tables of same page anyone please suggest solution,dir-pagination is working fine for first table but for second table it is not working properly, when we switch page for first table second table pages also get switch.

```
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>_id1</th>   
                            <th>modifiedDate1</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           <tr dir-paginate = "result in searchResult1 |filter:search |itemsPerPage:5"> 
                            <td>{{result._id}}</td>
                            <td>{{result.modifiedDate | date:"MM-dd-yyyy h:mma"}}</td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table> 
                    <dir-pagination-controls class="pull-right"
                            max-size="6"
                            direction-links="true"
                            boundary-links="true">
                       </dir-pagination-controls>


                       <table>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>_id2</th>   
                            <th>modifiedDate2</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           <tr dir-paginate = "row in searchResult2 |filter:search |itemsPerPage:5"> 
                            <td>{{row._id}}</td>
                            <td>{{row.modifiedDate | date:"MM-dd-yyyy h:mma"}}</td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table> 
                    <dir-pagination-controls class="pull-right"
                            max-size="6"
                            direction-links="true"
                            boundary-links="true">
                       </dir-pagination-controls>
```

Comment: Set unique pagination id for each instance like ``<tr dir-paginate pagination-id="paginate1" ></tr>``  and use the same paginate id in respective paginate controller like ``<dir-pagination-controls pagination-id="paginate1"></dir-pagination-controls>``. Refer https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination#multiple-pagination-instances-on-one-page

Comment: thanks sameer it is working thank you...

Answer (score -1):

Set unique pagination id for every table in a single page

```
</table>
```

**strong text**